# Copy/paste images from phone to desktop, files are corrupted and huge (2gb+)

Tags: file-transfer, windows, images, data-corruption

I linked my Android phone (v6.0) to my Windows laptop, located the phone's DCIM folder in File Manager and copy/pasted images from my phone onto my laptop's hard drive.

Some of the images are corrupted, can't be recognised as a bitmap, and are 2GB+ whereas on the phone they would have been 2-5MB. It seems to be a date thing, as it is all images past a certain date. It also affected some videos and again it is all videos past a certain date, although a different date to the images.

Is this a common problem, and what causes it? I'm assuming the images are lost as I deleted them from the phone once I saw they had successfully been pasted, without checking that the files were still readable.

Comment: What was your USB setting on? MTP is best suited for such transfer// It is far more better to use an app like [Folder Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) to ensure safe transfer on a one time as also periodic update

Comment: I don't know if you mean USB setting of the phone or laptop - either way, I hadn't changed anything from standard. Most of the files transferred fine though, so unsure why it would affect some but not all files, and specifically the latest files.

Comment: Enable developer options and Android Debug Bridge (adb) and copy (pull) the files via adb. MTP is a very bad protocol (another bad design by Microsoft).

Comment: @Robert can you point me to a tutorial or so. Usually I plug my phone to PC Windows, press file transfer on the phone, and use explorer from PC. Some photos are corrupted and once the entire SD was. Perhaps the method you suggest can help me. Thx.

Comment: @Alchimista try https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/ and then use `adb pull` to download files or folders from your device. There is also a tool called [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync) which can synchronize directories in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to reading the corrupted files (think they're long gone) but a few other people's experience indicate that it occurs when there is very little free memory left on the phone and memory earnings have been ignored. So take files off your phone regularly and you shouldn't have this problem.